# Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.draw is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, 2d

I have this javascript code that i'm using to draw a little square on a canvas object, and make it move left or right, but i'm receiving this error and i don't know why.

```
function Walker(canvas, ctx) {
    console.log("Received canvas with (" + canvas.width + ", " + canvas.height + ")");

    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width) + 1);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height) + 1);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = ctx;

    this.draw = function(x = this.x, y = this.y) {
        console.log("Drawing at (" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")");

        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 5);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.closePath();
    };

    this.walk = function() {
        left_or_right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

        if(left_or_right === 0) {
            console.log("Moving right");
            this.x += 1;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Moving left");
            this.x -= 1;
        }

        this.draw(this.x, this.y);
    };

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = new Walker(canvas, ctx);

w.draw();
setInterval(w.walk, 10000);
```

This is my .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
    <script src="../scripts/walk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your code.The problem is here

```
setInterval(function(){
       w.walk();
    }, 10000);
```

When you pass `w.walk` as an parameter, it gets out the function from the object.If the function is getted out it loses it's `context`.So in the w.walk's copy the `this` is not your `w`. In this case you have many variants to achieve to your goal.

**1)** You can use an wrapper function like in my code.
**2)** You can use an `bind` function - `setInterval(w.walk.bind(w), 1000 }`

```js
function Walker(canvas, ctx) {
    console.log("Received canvas with (" + canvas.width + ", " + canvas.height + ")");

    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width) + 1);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height) + 1);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = ctx;

    this.draw = function(x = this.x, y = this.y) {
        console.log("Drawing at (" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")");

        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 5);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.closePath();
    };

    this.walk = function() {
        left_or_right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

        if(left_or_right === 0) {
            console.log("Moving right");
            this.x += 1;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Moving left");
            this.x -= 1;
        }

        this.draw(this.x, this.y);
    };

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = new Walker(canvas, ctx);

w.draw();
setInterval(function(){
   w.walk();
}, 10000);
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: I've added my .html file.

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver!